# Adding a string that has quotes in it to a StringBuilder

Tags: c#, string

I have a string builder object and I am appending some values to it, one of the values I need to add is this:

```
<Literal datatypeIRI="&rdf;PlainLiteral">
```

but when I copy-paste it and add it to the stringbuilder object, it gives error and thinks that sring parameter is not completed yet...I also tried to put a "@" at the beginning of it, but still the same problem.

Comment: can you show us your code where you're adding it ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`"` characters need to be escaped. For normal strings, use `\"`, for @ strings use `""`.

e.g. `"<Literal datatypeIRI=\"&rdf;PlainLiteral\">"`

Answer (score 3):

You need to escape the embedded `"`:

```
"<Literal datatypeIRI=\"&rdf;PlainLiteral\">"
```

Or:

```
@"<Literal datatypeIRI=""&rdf;PlainLiteral"">"
```